# Drawing Mass-Spring

Tags: tikz-pgf, physics

I am attempting to make this into a Tikz Picture but it seemed like copy pasting stuff until it worked out didn't seem to work for me this time so would anyone be able to help me out to make this in LaTeX? Currently making a few physics questions and I would like to not just copy and paste this drawing on it. Thanks in advance.

[image: Mass-Spring]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!. Perhaps this post can be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54824/appending-a-line-of-fixed-length-to-a-spring-drawn-with-tikz-coil

Comment: Yeah those are the ones I tried to use but I have no clue how to turn it the orientation that I want.

Comment: Did the provided answer solve your problem? If yes, consider accepting/upvoting it.

Comment: Did the provided answer solve your problem? If yes, consider accepting/upvoting it.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have something to begin with. The code of the spring was taken from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54824/224762) question from @JohnD e.g. the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54852/224762) of @user11232.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,snakes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,thick}]

\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={aspect=0.5, segment length=1mm, amplitude=2mm,coil}]

\draw[thick] (0,0) --(0,3);
\draw[thick] (0,0) --(3,0) node[draw=none,xshift=5pt]{\tiny $x$};

\node at(0,0.25) (a) [draw=none] {};
\node at (2,0.25)(b) [minimum size=0.5cm,label=$\rightarrow$] {m};


\draw [spring] (a) -- (b) node[draw=none,pos=.5,right=.25cm] {};
\node at (2,-1)(c) [draw=none,yshift=5pt] {\tiny $x=0$};
\draw[dashed] (b.south) -- (c.north);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]