# Illustrating Hooke's law with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw mechanical springs in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41608/draw-mechanical-springs-in-tikz)

I'm trying to draw a nice looking spring to demonstrate Hooke's law. Essentially something which would have the following:

1. One spring at the equilibrium point and another one slightly stretched.
2. The amount of stretch marked by some variable.

I can't seem to figure this out. The part about drawing a nice looking spring seem especially annoying.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  See if [Draw mechanical springs in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41608/draw-mechanical-springs-in-tikz) helps, and if not please compose a  fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows what you have done so far so that we know exactly the problem that you are having.