# Could anyone help to draw the picture and give me direction to learn how to do it as well please?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: Parabol physics]

I would like not only to know how to do it but also with any help to point out to me some resources in order to be able to draw any Physics figures out there.

Comment: Take the following examples as a starting point: [Oblique incidence](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/oblique-incidence/), [Polarization state of light](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/polarization-state-of-light/), [Draw mechanical springs in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41621/110998). If you want to look up some of the `tikz` commands, either use the `tikz` manual, or see [A very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). There are also several online tutorials, google for "tutorial tikz".

Comment: I am using Latex for several days now. I don't know how to draw for the time being. No worry I am going to learn by doing.

Comment: So try first to read the manual! E.g. read the interesting parts of the [TikZ manual on CTAN.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Comment: I have been reading and doing all exemples in the first 100 pages as @HenriMenke point out to me. Still I can't figure out any mechanical figures. My problem is to find the right package to draw I think e.g here a player and the hoop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There you go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  % Ground
  \fill[pattern=north east lines] (-.5,-.3) rectangle (5.5,0);

  % Axes
  \draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node[above] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,2.2) node[right] {$z$};
  \draw[->] (-.5,1.25) node[left] {$\vec{g}$} -- (-.5,.75);

  % Parabola
  \def\a{-.25}
  \def\xn{2.5}
  \draw[dashed,blue,->] plot[domain=0:5] (\x,{\a*((\x-\xn)^2 - (\xn)^2)});

  % Draw initial velocity
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (.5,{\a*(0-\xn)}) node[above left] {$\vec{v}_0$};
  \draw (.5,0) node[above right] {$\theta$} arc (0:{atan(\a*(0-\xn)/.5)}:.5);

  % Draw ball
  \def\xb{1}
  \node[draw,circle,shade,ball color=red] at (\xb,{\a*((\xb-\xn)^2 - (\xn)^2)}) {};
  \draw[->] (\xb,{\a*((\xb-\xn)^2 - (\xn)^2)}) -- +(.5,{\a*(\xb-\xn)}) node[above] {$\vec{v}(t)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Just for fun!

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\foreach \xb in {0,.1,...,5} {
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    % Ground
    \fill[pattern=north east lines] (-.5,-.3) rectangle (5.5,0);

    % Axes
    \draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node[above] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,2.2) node[right] {$z$};
    \draw[->] (-.5,1.25) node[left] {$\vec{g}$} -- (-.5,.75);

    % Parabola
    \def\a{-.25}
    \def\xn{2.5}
    \draw[dashed,blue,->] plot[domain=0:5] (\x,{\a*((\x-\xn)^2 - (\xn)^2)});

    % Draw initial velocity
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (.5,{\a*(0-\xn)}) node[above left] {$\vec{v}_0$};
    \draw (.5,0) node[above right] {$\theta$} arc (0:{atan(\a*(0-\xn)/.5)}:.5);

    % Draw ball
    \node[draw,circle,shade,ball color=red] at (\xb,{\a*((\xb-\xn)^2 - (\xn)^2)}) {};
    \draw[->] (\xb,{\a*((\xb-\xn)^2 - (\xn)^2)}) -- +(.5,{\a*(\xb-\xn)}) node[above] {$\vec{v}(t)$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

After typesetting, produce the animated gif using ImageMagick

```bash
$ convert -density 300 -delay 8 -loop 0 -background white -alpha remove test.pdf test.gif
```

Comment: Wow thousand thanks @Henri Menke !!! Please I would like to  understand the code as well . Could you point out me resources who go straight to the point learning step by step how to figure out this and the animate gif because it  will be useful for Beamer Presentation?

Comment: @OusseynouDiagne I learned about all this by reading part I »Tutorials and Guidelines« in the [TikZ manual](texdoc.net/pkg/tikz).  Don't be scared by the huge page count.  Most of the manual is a reference and not intended for actual reading.  The tutorials are only about 100 pages but already after the first one you should be able to understand the above answer.

Comment: Thank you @HenriMenke it makes sense I know what is going on behind the scene. I am going to learn it down the road if I face any problem I will post the question.

Comment: Please could I have the animate code @HenriMenke

Comment: Please @HenriMenke add a player with a ball and the hoop as my new post. There are difference between the 2 posts.