# Tikz simple mechanical scheme

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

Could you help me with drawing of the transformer (see below)? I haven't enough experience with `tikz` to achieve this alone.

[image: Scheme of a simplified bridge]

Comment: You should always post what have you tried

Comment: You can start something with: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33951/tikzpicture-of-several-springs and then draw a line and two-triangles at the corner.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `@user177954's` nice answer using `straight lines`, you can also achieve it using `decorations` options available in the `TikZ` library.

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,
             decorations.pathmorphing,
             decorations.markings}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[help lines, step=1] (-2,-1)grid(2,2);
 \tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0cm,post
 length=0cm,segment length=8}]
% the line
\path (-2,1) node (p1) {};
\path (2,1) node (p2) {};
\draw[very thick] (p1) to  (p2);
%the triangles
\draw (-1.86,0.975) 
-- (-1.96,0.875)-- (-1.76,0.875) 
-- cycle;
\draw (1.86,0.975) 
-- (1.96,0.875)-- (1.76,0.875) 
-- cycle;
 \draw[spring] ($(p1.east)-(-0.3,0)$) -- ( $(p1.east)-(-0.3,1)$);
  \draw[spring] ($(p2.west)-(0.3,0)$) -- ( $(p2.west)-(0.3,1)$);
  % ground
  \draw[very thick] ($(p1.east)-(0,1)$) to ($(p1.east)-(-0.6,1)$);
 \fill [pattern = north east lines] ($(p1.east)-(0,1)$) rectangle ($(p1.east)-(-0.6,1.3)$);
 \draw[very thick] ($(p2.west)-(0,1)$) to ($(p2.west)-(0.6,1)$);
 \fill [pattern = north east lines] ($(p2.west)-(0,1)$) rectangle ($(p2.west)-(0.6,1.3)$);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

which would give you:

[image]

For easy reference, you can also use `grid lines` in the environment for assitive plotting and referencing your nodes. As you get a hold of it, you can always skip (which unfortunately, I don't ;)).

Answer (score 3):

Really just for fun (because I wanted to try out how much one can abuse `/.list`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trian/.style={anchor=north,regular polygon,regular polygon
sides=3},zig/.style={insert path={-- ++(-#1,-#1) -- ++(#1,0)}}]
\draw[very thick] (0,0) node[trian,thin,draw,anchor=north]{} -- (9,0)
node[trian,thin,draw,anchor=north]{};
\draw[thick] (3,0) [zig/.list={0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5}] node[below,pattern=north east
lines,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm,xshift=-0.25cm]{};
\draw[thick] (6,0) [zig/.list={0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5}] node[below,pattern=north east
lines,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm,xshift=-0.25cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple straight lines, don't require any experience in `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0.9840,6.7461) -- (0.7801,6.4168) -- (1.2036,6.4168) -- (0.9840,6.7461);
\draw (2.7719,6.7461) -- (2.4426,6.2756) -- (2.7876,6.2700) -- (2.4426,5.8992) -- (2.7876,5.8992) -- (2.4426,5.5709) -- (2.7876,5.5698) -- (2.4426,5.2405) -- (2.7876,5.2405);
\draw (2.4426,5.2405) -- (2.3245,5.0793);
\draw (2.5609,5.2405) -- (2.4428,5.0793);
\draw (2.6792,5.2405) -- (2.5611,5.0793);
\draw (2.7975,5.2405) -- (2.6794,5.0793);
\draw (6.1885,6.7461) -- (6.3924,6.4168) -- (5.9690,6.4168) -- (6.1885,6.7461);
\draw(4.5091,6.7461) -- (4.1798,6.2756) -- (4.5248,6.2700) -- (4.1798,5.8992) -- (4.5248,5.8992) -- (4.1798,5.5709) -- (4.5248,5.5698) -- (4.1798,5.2405) -- (4.5248,5.2405);
\draw (4.1798,5.2405) -- (4.0617,5.0793);
\draw (4.2981,5.2405) -- (4.1800,5.0793);
\draw (4.4164,5.2405) -- (4.2983,5.0793);
\draw (4.5347,5.2405) -- (4.4166,5.0793);
\draw (0.9840,6.7461) -- (6.1885,6.7461);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]